# running search and replace with normal

Tags: vim

im trying to do a search and replace inside a function with normal but while it runs it keeps saying there is a error here is the offending line

```
exec "%normal /1. row/\<CR>n3ddi\nDELIMITER $$\n\<esc>"
```

**I cannot figure out why it throws errors at me**

> I want to search for lines that have "1. row"
>
> then delete 3 lines  down from that line and add the text DELIMITER $$
>
> then move to the next one in the buffer

Comment: Generally when asking questions involving error messages it is useful if you post the exact error message in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this with `normal`, here is an alternative that seems to work.  This version removes the "1. row" line and two after:

```
exec "g/1. row/.,+2d|norm! ODELIMITER $$"
```

This one removes the three lines after "1. row":

```
exec "g/1. row/+1,+3d|norm! ODELIMITER $$"
```

Comment: +1. Can also use `d3` instead of `.,+2d` if that makes it easier to reason about. There is no need to use `exe` so it can be removed so just `g/1. row/d3|norm! ODELIMITER $$`.

Comment: Agreed on both counts, but I left the answer this way for a couple of reasons.  The question states that this will be in a function so chances are either the string to match or the replacement will come from a variable, the exec would be necessary in that case.  I also left the ranges because the question was a bit unclear and the ranges take care of either case.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have good reason to do it in this way.

- if you have `%`, the "next" (`n`) makes no sense, it will do on whole buffer anyway.
- you don't need the `\<ESC>` after the command was executed, vim stays in normal mode.

try this line:

```
exec "%normal /1. row/\<CR>3ddi\r\r\rWHATEVER TEXT $$\r\r\r"
```